# Is there a way of telling PhpStorm to behave with unnecessary uses as it does with regular ones?

Tags: phpstorm

When two PHP files are on the same namespace, adding a "use" to them for the other one is not necessary, but possible. However, PhpStorm inspection marks the unnecessary uses on PHP files as errors, warns about using them, and does not autocreate them when typing the class name on the file.

The thing is, I like having them on the file even that they are not necessary. That makes me easier to check the file dependencies, and to search-replace the namespaces when I move classes around. I know about the refactoring features of PhpStorm, but they are not always available for me and my co-workers.

So, is there a way of telling PhpStorm to behave with unnecessary uses as it does with regular ones? Not marking them as errors, autocompleting, etc.

Comment: Well .. you can tell it to stop complaining on existing entry .. but it will affect other bits as well. The inspection that reports it is `Inspections | PHP | Unused | Unused import` -- it will affect other (not actually used) imports as well (means: if you import some class and no longer use it, it will not notify about that once you disable that inspection).

Comment: For ref purposes: same on JetBrains Forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360005231339-Is-there-a-way-of-telling-PHPStorm-to-behave-with-unnecessary-uses-as-it-does-with-regular-ones-

Comment: Being notified about actual unused imports is a fine feature I do not want to lose.

Comment: Right now I may only suggest to check PhpStorm's Issue Tracker for existing tickets in this regard and submit a new one if none exists: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI